# How to see in the debug which datasource is used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My project uses 2 datasources, one for readwrite transactions, the other for readonly, how can I see in the debug which datasource is used for the request?

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-write.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties readWriteDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-only.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties readOnlyDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-only.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource readOnlyDataSource(DataSourceProperties readOnlyDataSourceProperties) {
        return readOnlyDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.read-write.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource readWriteDataSource(DataSourceProperties readWriteDataSourceProperties) {
        return  readWriteDataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public RoutingDataSource routingDataSource(DataSource readWriteDataSource, DataSource readOnlyDataSource) {
        RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(TransactionType.READ_WRITE, readWriteDataSource);
        dataSourceMap.put(TransactionType.READ_ONLY, readOnlyDataSource);
        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(readWriteDataSource);

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor dialectProcessor() {

        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) {
                    ((HibernateJpaVendorAdapter) bean).getJpaDialect().setPrepareConnection(false);
                }
                return bean;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

how to see in the debug which datasource to use, where to set a breakpoint

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the breakpoint in the above code will not work during runtime because the configurations will be initialized during application startup. If this is a spring boot application we can try this setting in application properties or YAML file:
`logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG`
or we can try this:
`org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG`

If DEBUG is not helpful, change it to TRACE (too many logs!).

If above two are not helpful, then we need to check the steps given by the SME in JPA: https://vladmihalcea.com/log-sql-spring-boot/